# C# - how to remove declaration and element in XMLDocument that have namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, nodes

I would like to remove ***XML Declaration*** and ***Info*** tag from my XML document below in C# code. I have tried with sample code as show below, but it seems does not works because I still see it in final xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2021-05-31T23:01:37.6988918+07:00" Version="16.1" xmlns="http://www.localhost.com/2007/00">
  <Originator CompanyShortName="SITA" />
  <Class>
    <Left>
      <Code CodeContext="3">R12</Code>     
    </Left>
    <Right>
      <Mode RepeatIndex="1" CodeContext="0">ARRIVED</Mode>
      <Status xsi:nil="true" />      
      <Time Qualifier="START" CodeContext="9750" RepeatIndex="1" TimeType="ACT">2021-05-31T21:54:00Z</Time>
      <Time Qualifier="END" CodeContext="0000" RepeatIndex="2" TimeType="">2021-05-31T21:49:00Z</Time>
      <Info>
        <Type CodeContext="3">772</Type>
        <SubType xsi:nil="true" />
        <Reg>T9056</Reg>
        <Tail xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fleet xsi:nil="true" />
      </Info>
    </Right>
  </Class>
</Root>
```

Below is the code that I have tried with

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();           
   xmlDoc.Load("data.xml");


    XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    //Remove 
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//xsi:Info", namespaceManager);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes){
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);                
    }

    //Remove Declaration
    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc) {
        if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration ) {
            xmlDoc.RemoveChild(node);
        }
    }
```

Here is what I want to get finally

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2021-05-31T23:01:37.6988918+07:00" Version="16.1" xmlns="http://www.localhost.com/2007/00">
  <Originator CompanyShortName="SITA" />
  <Class>
    <Left>
      <Code CodeContext="3">R12</Code>     
    </Left>
    <Right>
      <Mode RepeatIndex="1" CodeContext="0">ARRIVED</Mode>
      <Status xsi:nil="true" />      
      <Time Qualifier="START" CodeContext="9750" RepeatIndex="1" TimeType="ACT">2021-05-31T21:54:00Z</Time>
      <Time Qualifier="END" CodeContext="0000" RepeatIndex="2" TimeType="">2021-05-31T21:49:00Z</Time>
    </Right>
  </Class>
</Root>
```

Would you mind to guide me how to do it to get expected result as needed?

Comment: is this desired `<Code CodeContext="3">R12</Airline>`?

Comment: I corrected the xml (see my precedent comment) and your code work perfectly. Just care, `XmlDocument.Load` wait a file path as parameter (not xml content).

Comment: This part XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//xsi:Info", namespaceManager); return 0 nodes. Seems it can not find the node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the right namespace. `Info` doesn't have any namespace prefix so we need to see what the default namespace is at that point in the document.

Looking back up, we can see that a default namespace of `http://www.localhost.com/2007/00` is declared on the `Root` element:

> ```
> <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2021-05-31T23:01:37.6988918+07:00" Version="16.1" 
>       xmlns="http://www.localhost.com/2007/00">
> ```

So, to remove the info nodes, we need to refer to **that** namespace, not the XML Schema Instance one:

```
    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("abc", "http://www.localhost.com/2007/00");

    //Remove 
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//abc:Info", namespaceManager);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }
```

Note, namespace *prefixes* only have "local" meanings. We don't *have* to use the `xsi` prefix to reference the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace; Equally, I can use `abc` above to reference the `http://www.localhost.com/2007/00` namespace.